# SAXParser catch nothing with minimized XML document

Tags: java, android, rss, sax

I'm running a small Android project which could read RSS/Atom Feed documents, using SAX library. Everything works well for default RSS sources, but with minimized sources (without spaces or new line tokens), it produces nothing but a list of blank items. My logs in Log cat also display nothing. I double check this problems with variant RSS sites, but problems still there. Below is my inheritance class of `DefaultHandler` which I use to handle Rss sources

```
public class RssContentHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private static final int UNKNOWN_STATE = -1;
    private static final int ELEMENT_START = 0;
    private static final int TITLE_END = 1;
    private static final int DESCRIPTION_END = 2;
    private static final int LINK_END = 3;
    private static final int PUBDATE_END = 4;
    private static final int CHANNEL_END = 5;

    private int iState = UNKNOWN_STATE;
    private String fullCharacters;
    private boolean itemFound = false;
    private RssItem rssItem;
    private RssFeed rssFeed;

    public RssContentHandler() {
    }

    public RssFeed getFeed() {
        return this.rssFeed;
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() {
        rssItem = new RssItem();
        rssFeed = new RssFeed();
        Log.i("startDocument", "startDocument");
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() {
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String _uri, String _localName, String _qName, Attributes _attributes) {
        if (_localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
            itemFound = true;
            rssItem = new RssItem();
            this.iState = UNKNOWN_STATE;
        } else
            this.iState = ELEMENT_START;
        fullCharacters = "";
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String _uri, String _localName, String _qName) {
        if (_localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
            this.rssFeed.addItem(this.rssItem);
        else if (_localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
            this.iState = TITLE_END;
        else if (_localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description"))
            this.iState = DESCRIPTION_END;
        else if (_localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
            this.iState = LINK_END;
        else if (_localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate"))
            this.iState = PUBDATE_END;
        else if (_localName.equalsIgnoreCase("channel"))
            this.iState = CHANNEL_END;
        else
            this.iState = UNKNOWN_STATE;
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] _ch, int _start, int _length) {
        String strCharacters = new String(_ch, _start, _length);
        if (this.iState == ELEMENT_START)
            fullCharacters += strCharacters;
        else {
            if (!itemFound) {
                switch (this.iState) {
                case TITLE_END:
                    this.rssFeed.setTitle(fullCharacters);
                    break;
                case DESCRIPTION_END:
                    this.rssFeed.setDescription(fullCharacters);
                    break;
                case LINK_END:
                    this.rssFeed.setLink(fullCharacters);
                    break;
                case PUBDATE_END:
                    this.rssFeed.setPubDate(fullCharacters);
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                switch (this.iState) {
                case TITLE_END:
                    this.rssItem.setTitle(fullCharacters);
                    Log.i("characters", fullCharacters);
                    break;
                case DESCRIPTION_END:
                    this.rssItem.setDescription(fullCharacters);
                    break;
                case LINK_END:
                    this.rssItem.setLink(fullCharacters);
                    break;
                case PUBDATE_END:
                    this.rssItem.setPubDate(fullCharacters);
                    break;
                }
            }
            this.iState = UNKNOWN_STATE;            
        }
    }
}
```

and snippet to setup the parser:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
    try {
        request.setURI(new URI(_strUrl));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    Reader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
    RssContentHandler rssContentHandler = new RssContentHandler();
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource();
    inputSource.setCharacterStream(inputStream);

    SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
    saxParser.parse(inputSource, rssContentHandler);

    this.rssFeed = rssContentHandler.getFeed();
```

P/s: i'm using Android 2.3 x86 installed on VirtualBox for Debugging, and these sources work fine with the built-in RSS Reader app come with the x86 version. So what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try with _qName instead of _localName.

Your xml contains CDATA so You cann't parse the XML response with your current parser. You have to use LexicalHandler for parsing Raw HTML.

```
public class MyHandler implements LexicalHandler {

  public void startDTD(String name, String publicId, String systemId)
   throws SAXException {}
  public void endDTD() throws SAXException {}
  public void startEntity(String name) throws SAXException {}
  public void endEntity(String name) throws SAXException {}
  public void startCDATA() throws SAXException {}
  public void endCDATA() throws SAXException {}

  public void comment (char[] text, int start, int length)
   throws SAXException {

    String comment = new String(text, start, length);
    System.out.println(comment);

  }
```

You can also parse your XML with DOM if memory is not the issue. For more help visit [Handling Lexical Events](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPSAX11.html)

Comment: Still not working, an example for this case is from [link](http://genk.vn/trang-chu.rss)

Comment: I found my problem is the different between Trees-based and Events-based API, now they're working fine with XmlPullParser